# PowerShell - Restore directory of script location while being ran as administrator

Tags: powershell

**My Situation:** 
I have to run a PowerShell script as Administrator (because of accessing a privileged folder) and my script is also referencing files in the same directory as the script. I need to use a relative file path but I can't due to PowerShell switching the directory to `C:\WINDOWS\system32` when ran as admin.

> In PowerShell, is there a way to restore the directory to the current directory that the script is located?

**My Script:** (will be ran as admin)

```
Copy-Item -Path .\file1.txt -Destination 'C:\Users\privileged_folder'
```

**Directory Structure:**

```
MyDir\
    file1.txt
    myscript.ps1 <- ran as admin
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## By Changing Location

In your script, you can set the location to the script folder. From within your script, either of the following techniques will work:

```
# PowerShell 3+
cd $PSScriptRoot

# PowerShell 2
cd ( Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition )
```

Changing to `$PSScriptRoot` works in all currently supported versions of PowerShell, but using [`Split-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/split-path?view=powershell-5.1) to get the script directory is useful if you for some reason still have nodes running PowerShell 2.

---

If you want to change back to the previous directory after your script is done executing (probably a good move) you can also make use of [`Push-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/push-location?view=powershell-5.1) and [`Pop-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/pop-location?view=powershell-5.1) instead of [`cd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-location?view=powershell-5.1) or [`Set-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-location?view=powershell-5.1):

```
# Also aliased to pushd
Push-Location $PSScriptRoot

# My script stuff

# Also aliased to popd
Pop-Location
```

These two cmdlets treat locations as a stack - `Push-Location` changes your location and adds the directory to the location stack while `Pop-Location` will remove the current directory from the stack and return you to the previous location. It works much like push and pop operations on arrays.

---

## By Prefixing the Relative Paths

You could also prefix your relative paths in your script with either `$PSScriptRoot` or `( Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition )` as shown in the previous section. If we attach the prefix to the otherwise relative path of `file1.txt`:

```
$filepath1 = "${PSScriptRoot}\file1.txt"
```

Now you have an absolute path to `file1.txt`. Note that this technique will work with *any relative path* to `$PSScriptRoot`, it does not have to be in the same folder as your `ps1` script.